# Having a java program turn into a exe file

Tags: java, exe

I'm still really new to coding, and was just wondering if the following was possible.

I created a program just for fun using java, and want to put the program on a USB stick for my friends to see. But after I finished the program I found out I can only make '.jar' files, which will need to have JDK installed to run.

Is there anyway to have my program converted to a exe file, so that my friends/family can see the program I created without having to install all the java files(jdk etc)?

Comment: Why would you create exe a platform dependant software?

Comment: Didn't you search at Google? A quick search gave me these many results: https://www.google.com/search?q=jar+to+exe&oq=jar+to+exe&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2704j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8